# Cant start a new project in Android Studio, nothing happens

Tags: android, ubuntu

I am new to Ubuntu and Android, and I tried to install Android Studio and succeeded in that matter, but when I click Start a new project nothing happens. I tried reinstalling, but it didnt help. Any ideas?

EDIT:
i managed to create project manually using terminal, but in android studio I still cant create project nor edit existing project (some IDE error is thrown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be more specific (screenshot or quotes of error), so try this:

> In Android Studio, go to Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project
>   Structure -> Platform Settings (SDK) choose the Android SDK, set the
>   build target and click on apply.

Comment: I get error Project SDK is not defined in project. I added new paths ~/Android/Sdk, ~/Android/Sdk/tools and ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools but it isnt really helping much..

Comment: Also when starting Android Studio now I started to get new errors
http://oi61.tinypic.com/2zz6lj5.jpg

Comment: When I enable Android support I get exception 
http://oi57.tinypic.com/2z7j1p5.jpg

Answer (score 0):

After successfull installation of Android studio,sdk and jdk i was not able to open new project in Android in Android Studio on windows 7. This got resolved by doing the below settings,
Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure -> Platform Settings (SDK) choose the Android SDK >click Apply and Ok.

You are good to go. Please note that you need jdk 1.7 to work with Android studio.